# Why did I got error creating EKS Cluster? InvalidParameterException: unsupported Kubernetes version

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

My eks.tf file

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {}

module "myapp-vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.7.0"
  
  name = "myapp-vpc"
  cidr = var.vpc_cidr_block
  private_subnets = var.private_subnets_cidr_blocks
  public_subnets = var.public_subnets_cidr_blocks
  azs = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  single_nat_gateway = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
   "kubernetes.io/cluster/myapp-cluster" = "shared"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
   "kubernetes.io/cluster/myapp-cluster" = "shared"
   "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb" = 1
  }

  public_subnet_tags = {
   "kubernetes.io/cluster/myapp-cluster" = "shared"
   "kubernetes.io/role/elb" = 1
  }
```

I got this error

```
│ Error: error creating EKS Cluster (myapp-cluster): InvalidParameterException: unsupported Kubernetes version
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "073bff37-1d18-4d11-82c9-226b92791a70"
│   },
│   ClusterName: "myapp-cluster",
│   Message_: "unsupported Kubernetes version"
│ }
│ 
│   with module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/eks/main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this":
│   11: resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this" {
```

I went for terraform init and plan.
What should I check in my terraform.tfstate file?

Comment: And where is the code block for the EKS module invocation?

Comment: No,I have vpn,tf and variables.tf files.

Comment: Are you maybe in the wrong directory? Because it seems to me that the error output is related to the module call for the EKS cluster: `module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.this[0]`.

Comment: Ok,I will take a look again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to change the versions of kubernetes/cluster? I had the same issue and I changed the version of the cluster and it worked.